# How to give background color dynamically using jQuery index?

Tags: jquery

I have a markup like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
</div>
```

I want to give background color using jQuery `index()` for any `div` inside the container (I will get indexes dynamically from the server).

Answer (score 3):

use [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
 $(".container").children().eq(0).css("background-color",'red') //this will change background of first div
```

with your requirement

```
 var yourindex='0';
 $(".container").children().eq(yourindex).css("background-color",'red')
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DG7Ye/)

Answer (score 2):

Try with `.eq()` and `:eq()`:

```
$('.container div').eq(idx).css('background','purple');

$('.container div:eq('+idx+')').css('background','purple');
```

Comment: The [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method takes an optional selector or element and returns an integer, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".container div:nth-child(0)").css("someecssName)
```